# Where is the utilities menu?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I can't find utilities menu anywhere. I installed the latest version of this game from Google Play but it seems that it's missing the utilities menu. I have the mission to purchase final blast but I don't know how to.

I am using the Samsung Note 3 phone.

Comment: Try redownloading the game

Comment: what do you mean by "utilities menu" ?

Comment: In stash where we purchase headstat and fainal blast.

Answer (score -1):

They removed it from jetpack joyride

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the Arqade. We generally prefer here if you can add a source to your information and add a bit of detail, in this case, maybe adding when it was removed.